# I started with Jquery and its going not so good

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

so... today I started to learn a bit of jquery and Im trying to make a little text-animation with the words 'improvise' 'adapt' and 'overcome' (idea comes from meme) but when I use

```
improvise.animate({left: "50px"})
```

with improvise being the text-element, just nothing happens.

Here is my code(very bad code, but Im beginner), I hope you can help me.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="container">
        <h1 id="improvise">Improvise</h1>
        <h1 id="adapt">Adapt</h1>
        <h1 id="overcome">Overcome</h1>
        </div>
<script       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let improvise = $("#improvise")
let adapt = $("#adapt")
let overcome = $("#overcome")

improvise.hide()
adapt.hide()
overcome.hide()

function start(){
setTimeout(function(){improvise.fadeIn()}, 0)
setTimeout(function(){adapt.fadeIn()}, 1000)
setTimeout(function(){overcome.fadeIn()}, 2000)
setTimeout(function(){improvise.animate({left: "50px"}, 500)}, 3000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling your `start()` function anywhere, so that's why nothing's really happening.

And inside your css you need to give your `#improvise` element the `position: relative` property.

Comment: Tnx, it is meant to not call start but I didn't know anything about the css tag